# Abrir aplicativo externo dentro da aplicaçao

Tags: java, android, arduino, ip

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação que faz comando via *Arduino*. Até aqui tudo ocorre bem,  mas no projeto o usuário vai ter  acesso a câmera externa via IP, porem não faço ideia como faço isso.

**Modelo da câmera:** IP Camera P2P

**IP:** NIP-288696-FACBF

Um aplicativo chamado P2PCam_HD funciona bem com essa câmera, mas eu também não sei chamar esse aplicativo do meu! Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma sugestão, caso seja uma câmera com entrada de rede e seu **Arduino** possui um *shield edhernet*, a primeira coisa que deve ser feita é conectá-la com um cabo para configuração. O WiFi só funciona depois de corretamente configurado. Assim você pode criar uma página web que pode ser visualizado através de uma **URL**, por exemplo:

```
http://192.168.0.6:8080/index.html
```

Se for possível fazer desta forma, aí você cria um [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) para acesso através do seu aplicativo.

#### Detalhes

- [Android WebView Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm)
- [Como configurar uma câmera IP WiFi](http://www.tudovemdachina.com/como-configurar-uma-camera-ip-wifi/)

Comment: já esta configurada a camera, mas eu queria fazer algo do tipo clica em um botão  abrir  a camera, ol algo do tipo sem precisa criar algo fora do android studio, você pode me orienta?

Comment: Mas a intenção é essa mesmo! Você tem um _shield ethernet_?

Comment: tenho sim , mas   os comando arduino é por bluetoh  por internet eu não faço idéia cyom fazer isso ,  tenho que apresenta esse projeto sexta agora to muito preuculpado, por favor se pode me ajuda a resolver esse unico problema meu.

Comment: Cara, confesso que já passei por isso, apresentação, correria e tudo mais. Mas então, se fosse meu caso, tendo em vista o seu problema, eu usaria exatamente essa minha resposta para resolver. A não ser que eu não tenha entendido o que você quis dizer com a pergunta. Minha sugestão é que você altere sua pergunta detalhando mais ela, especificando o que você já tentou. Insira exatamente qual Arduíno você tem, com qual api você quer desenvolver seu app. Se você detalhar mais, com certeza terá outras respostas, mas se você não explicar direito, as pessoas nem fazem questão de responder.

Comment: Obg pela atenção o que eu queria mesmo era poder ter acesso a camera ip pelo meu aplicativo android ,  ou seja clica em um botão e abrir outra activiry mostrando o video da camera,  ja fiz umas 4 pergunta e não  to tendo resultado ,  se você podesse me passa algum meio de comunicar com você algum chat iria te mostra o meu problema com detalhes, muito preuculpado.